# Use class inheritance with container-aware abstract base class

Tags: php, yaml, symfony

In Symfony 3.x we use an API Layer which delivers Doctrine Entities as JSON-Responses (with JMSSerializer and FOSRestBundle) - think of it somehow as kind of custom ObjectNormalizers of the Symfony Serialization component.

A couple of these API classes need to be container aware. Currently we use global `$kernel` which is for so many reasons bad practise.

This is what I tried so far (very simplified):

**Abstract Class**

```
abstract class ApiWrapper implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container

    }
}
```

**BaseClass**

```
protected class BaseApi extends ApiWrapper
{
    //...some stuff
}
```

**RealApiClass1**

```
protected class MyApi1 extends BaseApi
{
    protected $entity;

    public function __construct(SomeEntityClass $entity) {
        $this->entity = $entity;

    }
}
```

**RealApiClass2**

```
protected class MyApi2 extends BaseApi
{
    protected $entity;

    public function __construct(AnotherEntityClass $entity) {
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    bundle.api_wrapper: 
        class: ApiWrapper
        abstract: true
        shared: false // to make sure to get a new instance everytime it's called
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
    bundle.base_api:
        class: BaseApi
        parent: api_wrapper
    bundle.my_api:
        class: MyApi
        parent: base_api
```

**Controller**

```
$myApi = new MyApi1($myEntity);
```

I can see that `$myApi` has an property container but it delivers `null`.
Is there any way to share the container in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but instead of trying to break the initial design of the Container etc. You may want to properly explain why  do you want to do that and find a proper solution. Everything here smells very bad, even on mid-term. Do you encounter any cyclic dependencies issue?

Comment: As already pointed out, the new operator has no knowledge of the Symfony container.  One possibility is to make an api factory class.  But in reality, there are very few reasons to inject the complete container.

Comment: thanks @Cerad, can you point me some direction for a factory class? i'd be OK as well if I could inject a couple (actually at the moment 2) of defined services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of how you configure the services it can be a bit of a pain to map entities to their api class.  One approach to doing this is to use a factory for actually creating the api classes.  This has an added benefit of being a bit easier to configure.

This code has not been tested so there could easily be some syntax errors.

```
class ApiFactory
{
    $container;
    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    public function create($entity) {
        $api = null;
        switch(get_class($entity)) { // Map entity to api class
            case MyEntity1::class :
                $api = new MyApi1($entity);
                break;
            case MyEntity2::class :
                $api = new MyApi2($entity);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Oops');
        }
        // Steal a trick from the controller resolver
        if ($api instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
            $api->setContainer($this->container);
        }
        return $api;
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no real need for your abstract ApiWrapper class.  If a particular api needs the container then just have it implement the container aware interface and add the trait.

```
// Usage in a controller
$apiFactory = $this->get('my_api_factory');
$api = $apiFactory->create($myEntity);

// services.yml
services:
    my_api_factory:
        class: ApiFactory
        arguments: ['@service_container']
```

There are a number of variations that you use.  I think it would be better to define a service for each api and inject the exact dependencies it needs instead of the container.  You could name each api service using the class name of the api.  Your api factory would then just pull out the desired fully configured api from the container using the entity class name to generate the key.

Comment: looks like a very clean but given the ugly dependency (which we need to get rid of sooner than later) still a pretty decoupled solution. I will give it a try - please let me prototype it before I accept the answer. and of course it's untested - let me do my job ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you must retrieve the API via the container as example:

<kbd>Controller</kbd>

```
$myApi = $this->get('bundle.my_api');
```

Comment: thanks - is there any other option to not define and use all of these classes as 'standard' services?

Comment: Hi @LBA i don't know but you can try the auto-wire service features. Let me know if you need more helps!